# How long is a piece of $string.... too long... php

Tags: php

what am I doing wrong here guys?

```
 $string = "string How Long is a Piece of String?";

if $string = <5;
{
echo "string is less than 5";
}

else
{
echo "string is more than 5";
}
```

Comment: So many things..

Comment: hahaha love the responses, come on guys I'm new at this  .. Really enjoying learning php at amazing how much I learn each day.. Thanks for the help

Comment: I would have upvoted if it were `if $string = <3`.

Comment: Great! Stack Overflow finally implemented bonus points! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1st, condition are in parenthesis.

2nd, you don't need a ; after a condition.

3rd, less than is simply < not <= unless you want to echo "string is less or equals than 5"

```
$string = "string How Long is a Piece of String?";

if (strlen($string) < 5)
{
   echo "string is less than 5";
}
else
{
   echo "string is more than 5";
}
```

Comment: =< is nothing, <= is "less than or equal to"

Comment: Don't forget 4th, you need strlen. Shown in code, but not stated.

Answer (score 2):

Others pointed out the syntax errors, to actually compare to the length of the string you need to use the `strlen` function:

```
$string = "string How Long is a Piece of String?";

if (strlen($string) < 5)
{
   echo "string is less than 5";
}
else
{
   echo "string is more than 5";
}
```

Comment: lmao, I forgot the obvious strlen. Sometimes when the answer is so easy you forget the obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Type juggling it is called:
http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

```
$string = "string How Long is a Piece of String?";
if ($string < 5)
```

string is cast to int, becomes 0

```
if (0 < 5)
```

true!

`strlen` / `mbstrlen` are possible candidates you're loking for

But that wasn't the question, there are obivously more things wrong with the code :)

Answer (score 1):

may be you're looking for the [strlen()](http://php.net/strlen) function?

Answer (score 0):

missing parentheses around if statement and no need for semi-colon? also less than or equal operator in wrong order. should be like this:

if ($string <=5)
{
echo "string is less than 5";
}

Answer (score 0):

Also note that if that string has multi byte chars it will return a *wrong* char count, but a byte count.

You'll probably need to know this down the track :) For now, get on top of your syntax.